# URL Rewriting for a Subsite?

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, redirect, url-rewriting

So this is what I'm trying to achieve...

I have a site with the URL with the following format:

*somedb.mysite.com*

*somedb* can be many different DBs. The problem is, different DBs require different versions of the site. These different versions are setup as subsites of the parent site.

For example *somedb.mysite.com/1.0* and *somedb2.mysite.com/2.0*

Currently I'm using Response.Redirect() in the parent site to redirect to the proper version. What I'm HOPING to do is to HIDE the version number so that all DBs appear to be using the same site, and so the URL appears the same if a DB is updated to a newer version.

I've been messing around with using RewritePath and Server.Transfer with not a lot of success... The main problem (from what I can gather) is that Rewrite and Transfer only work within the same site, but the individual versions are technically different subsites sites.

Does anybody have any ideas how I may be able to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you write your own handler to intercept incoming request for you subdomains

To achieve this you can implement the IHttpHandler and process the url redirection logic in t he ProcessRequest method

Here is a very good example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30907/The-Two-Interceptors-HttpModule-and-HttpHandlers

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned in the initial question. I have implemented my own handler to intercept the requests, it's dealing with the requests and redirecting appropriately where I'm having issues.